# Progressive Loading, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a page that has to render a huge set of query results - most of them with very, very small images. It is already paginated, so that won't solve my problem.

The query executes fine - it's very zippy, returns in about .0004 seconds, paginates itself out to the View - all is well in the land of Oz.

However there is some big trouble in that ASP.NET MVC dumps the page when it is ready, not as it is loaded. Is there any way around this?

I tried using jQuery to lace through div layers and draw partial views - this alleviated some of the problem, but it still just 'hangs' on the page until the whole thing is ready to be drawn.

I was looking around and found a few suggestions about using Response.Write - but I couldn't uncover anything relevant to my case. Any ideas? The structure is as follows...

```
PartialView
- Category
  - IEnumerable<Models.Images> (List)

PartialView
- Page
  - IEnumerable<Models.Images> (List) (Paginated View)

View
- Gallery
-- Index
--- Categories (Ajax Loaded on Demand, not on View render.)
---- ViewPage (No specific model passed)
```

The problem is clearly the images, I've tested it several times. If I remove the  tags from the code, it renders quickly with just any data I tell it to. Each image is around 4 kb in size - so compressing them isn't likely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do.

First, make sure the results themselves are not inside tables.  IE (and perhaps other browsers) have to wait until the table has been fully loaded before rendering to the browser.

Secondly, there is a command called [Response.Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx) which will push the buffered output to the client.  You can call this repeatedly.  You may want to call it for every 10 items or so, for example.  If you can incorporate this into your code it should do the trick for you.

Comment: I like this answer more than mine. :)

Comment: Any idea of how to incorporate this? All I get is errors about Http Headers when I put it in the ActionResult.

Comment: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent. - is the specific error I get.

Comment: You'll need to put Response.Flush into an iterator that builds your output.  You might have to change the code around to make it work.  In the old days I would use a SqlDataReader, and call Response.Flush at the end of the loop to progressively display the results.  But you should be able to do the same thing with your List.

Comment: Hrnm. So how can one write a Partial View to the Response?

Comment: I'm not sure since I haven't messed around with Partial Views yet.

Answer (score 0):

About how many images are being loaded in a given request? As I'm sure you're aware the issue is less the size of the files and more the quantity of them- it takes longer to move a bunch of small files than an equally sized large file.

One thing to consider would be to send the page down with a specific sized set of results already populated and then use JavaScript (and perhaps scroll events) to dynamically load the rest. Ideally you should try to minimize the size of the initial request so that the page doesn't block user interaction for long; after that initial loading period you could then start pulling in the rest of the results.

Comment: About 2 or 3 images per request - sometimes up to 8, but usually between 2 and 3.